# Haskell, something similar to varargs for own datatypes?

Tags: haskell, types, tree, functional-programming, variadic-functions

I'm looking for something similar in Haskell as varargs are in Java.

For University I have to create a treelike data structure that consists of two types of knots:

1) Index-knots: consisting of 2 (here) Ints, followed by any amount of other knots

2) Data-knots: consisting of 1 (here) Int

My approach looks like this:

```
data MultTree a = Index a a (MultTree a) | Data a deriving Show
```

The bold Text is what has to be any amount of MultTrees.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not use a list? `data MultTree a = Index a a [MultTree a] | Data a`?

Comment: I tried it, but the types of the elements may vary, since there could be [Index 1 2 [Index 3 4 [Data 5]]] or [Index 1 2 [Data 3]] in the list at the same time and as far as i can tell those types don't match.

Comment: Do you get an error in GHC? The types shoud match just fine, since all items of the list are of type `MultTree a`, and the trees themselves are well-defined.

Comment: Thank! You are right, seems like i made a mistake before. And there is no other way you know to solve the Problem? I'm pretty new to Haskell :)

Comment: This looks fine to me, so have a go at it!

Comment: `Index` and `Data` are both constructors for the same type `MultTree a` so everything matches. Every constructor does not define its own type, there only `MultTree a` here.

Comment: You and [jublikon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4125633/jublikon) appear to have the same homework problem.